# Codificar en base 64 archivo C#

Tags: c#

Hola estoy codificando un archivo en base 64 en c#, pero para archivos grandes ya no funciona.

```
char[] base64 = new char[miArchivo.Length];
Convert.ToBase64CharArray(miArchivo, 0, miArchivo.Length, base64, 0);
return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64);
```

Lo he intentado con `MemoryStream` pero no ha funcionado, el problema está en el tamaño del char[] que en base64 ocupa mas creo.

Comment: _ya no funciona_ que significa? te lanza alguna excepción?

Comment: Hola: ¿grandes de que tamaño? Si no recuerdo mal hay una limitación en el .NET Framework para que ningún elemento en memoria sea mayor de 2 GB (puedo estar desactualizado). Pero si necesitas codificar archivos grandes en base64 ¿por qué no usar algún tipo de streaming mejor?

Comment: @yorodm eso es lo que intento, usar un memorystream lo he comentado, lo que querría es ir leyendo por bloques y codificando cada bloque pero no se como hacerlo, ya que para el Convert.ToBase64CharArray necesito tener un tamaño de bloque que no se como calcular ya que en b64 ocupa mas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada 3 *bytes* se convierten en 4 caracteres, porque sólo se utilizan 7 *bits* de cada carácter para codificar información. El *array* de destino debe tener al menos ese tamaño.

También ten en cuenta que si hay algún *byte* más porque el tamaño no es múltiplo de 3, se necesitan 4 bytes más. Es decir, para 5 bytes de entrada necesitarás 8 de salida, igual que si fueran 6.

Answer (score 0):

Te esta faltando considerar el tamaño del tipo char.

```
            var binaryData = File.ReadAllBytes("black-stormtrooper-64.png");

            long tamañoChar = sizeof(char);
            long arrayLength = binaryData.Length * tamañoChar;

            /*Normalizo en caso de que no termine de completar el tamaño.*/
            if (arrayLength % tamañoChar != 0)
            {
                arrayLength += tamañoChar - arrayLength % tamañoChar;
            }

            char[] base64CharArray = new char[arrayLength];

            Convert.ToBase64CharArray(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length, base64CharArray, 0);
            var res = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64CharArray);
```

Como alternativa a tu código podes hacer:

```
var binaryData = File.ReadAllBytes("black-stormtrooper-64.png");
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData);
```

Comment: Se necesitan más caracteres en Base64 que bytes de entrada, no es una correspondencia 1 a 1, sino 3 a 4.